# Grape API service response 400 bad request at Rails 4 when I sending a json request to it using curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, curl, ruby-grape

I don't know how to solve the 400 bad request that API service gives back to me. All I need are receiving json responses from API service, and the API service could communicate with many-type devices.

I'm building an all-json-request API service according to tutorial of Grape gem at GitHub.com https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape and GitHub.io http://intridea.github.io/grape/docs/index.html . After I sending a json request to the API service: localhost:3000/specified_vegetables using curl, which is construct with **Grape gem version 0.8.0** and located at **new empty Rails 4.1.1 project**, the API service give back the response:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /specified_vegetables/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Type:application/json
> Content-Length: 55
>
* upload completely sent off: 55 out of 55 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 56
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Request-Id: 87231177-b8f8-4084-b0ef-19445fa42fab
< X-Runtime: 0.220101
< Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.1/2015-02-26)
< Date: Thu, 01 Oct 2015 13:35:46 GMT
< Connection: Keep-Alive
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"error":"transaction_date is missing, name is missing"}
```

My curl request command: `curl -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -X GET http://localhost:3000/specified_vegetables/ -d '{"transaction_date" : "20131031", "name" : "金針筍"}' -v`
In my database, there is one record matched the conditions I've queried.

The log of rails server runs and it also includes the curl request:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-10-01 21:35:43] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-10-01 21:35:43] INFO  ruby 2.2.1 (2015-02-26) [x86_64-darwin10]
[2015-10-01 21:35:43] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=27004 port=3000


Started GET "/specified_vegetables/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-01 21:35:46 +0800
```

The following are my environment settings and codes.
The directory structure of API files in rails app:

> RailsApp.root/app/api/agriculture_transaction/base.rb
>   RailsApp.root/app/api/agriculture_transaction/v1/specified_vegetables.rb

Code of **base.rb**:

```
module AgricultureTransaction
        class Base < Grape::API
                format :json
                version 'v1'

                mount AgricultureTransaction::V1::SpecifiedVegetables
                mount AgricultureTransaction::V1::OverviewVegetables
        end
end
```

Code of **specified_vegetables.rb**

```
module AgricultureTransaction
       module V1
                class SpecifiedVegetables < Grape::API
                        format :json
                        default_format :json
                        version 'v1', using: :header, vendor: 'twitter'

                        resource :specified_vegetables do
                                desc "Get all transaction prices of all items today."
                                get :today do
                                        SpecifiedVegetable.where(transaction_date: Date.today).find_in_batches do |vegetables|
                                                vegetables
                                        end
                                end

                                desc "Get transaction prices of delegated item in a delegated day."
                                params do
                                        requires :transaction_date, type: Date, desc: 'code'
                                        requires :name, type: String
                                end
                                get do
                                        SpecifiedVegetable.where(transaction_date: params[:transaction_date], name: params[:name]).find_in_batches do |vegetables|
                                                vegetables
                                        end
                                end
                        end
                end
       end
end
```

The only one model in Rails app is **SpecifiedVegetable.rb**:

```
class SpecifiedVegetable < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.table_name = "specified_vegetable"
end
```

In **config/application.rb** file, I add two lines in rails **Application class**:

```
config.paths.add "app/api", glob: "**/*.rb"
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/api/*"]
```

In **config/routes.rb** file, I add one line in Rails.application.routes.draw:

```
mount AgricultureTransaction::Base => '/'
```

Above of all are information I could provide. Please help me to solve this problem or give me some keywords to search. I've find some articles, but they could not help me.

Comment: Hey, first of all, you dont need to specify the format again in the class, about the bad request, have you tried a simple get? with no params, just to know if the api is really working, besides can you show me your api routes?

Comment: @emerak : I remove the double json in the class and then have tried with simple get. It gives me back with null response. <br> The rake routes shows below:                       Prefix Verb URI Pattern Controller#Action
agriculture_transaction_base      /           AgricultureTransaction::Base

Comment: you should be pointing to /api/specified_vegetables/, is this available in github? I'm sure we can make this work, I worked with grape recently.

Comment: @emerak : Do you mean that I should make agriculture_transaction_base pointing to api/specified_vegetables in file: config/routes.rb ? It would not available in github and above files are everything in this new rails app.

Comment: are you still having trouble with this?

Comment: @emerak Hi, I have already solved it. What wrong I had is using fault query method. The right method for GET verb is to append parameters to tail of URL such as http://localhost:3000/specified_vegetables/query?transaction_date=20131031\&trade_location=%E4%B8%89%E9%87%8D%E5%B8%82